# Proper way to store data in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have basic SQL question for something I`ve done wrong. So I wish to ask what is the proper way to accomplish this.
I have Room table. Room have room size, name and wall color. The room have furniture table, it can have many furniture. What is the right way to connect multiple furniture to room. For example:

```
Room Table
roomID: 5
size: 15
wallColor: Blue
haveFurniture: 2,4,5 //This is the part I`m not sure about

Furniture Table
furnitureID 2
type: table
color: wood

Furniture Table
furnitureID 4
type: closet
color: wood

etc...
```

So, what is the right way to connect furniture to room. The user may create multiple rooms and multiple furniture

Comment: You want another table, called a junction table with one row per `Room` and `furnitureId`.

Comment: As @GordonLinoff mentioned you need to create M:M relation between Room and Furniture and to do this you would need a table (you can call it RoomFurniture) with colums RoomId and FurnitureId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a many-to-many (n-m) relation table to join the two.  Based on your notation:

```
RoomHasFurnature Table
roomID 5
furnitureID 2

RoomHasFurnature Table
roomID 5
furnitureID 4

RoomHasFurnature Table
roomID 5
furnitureID 5
```

You'd then use a join to pull that data out.  Here's a crude example:

```
SELECT * FROM Room
LEFT JOIN RoomHasFurnature USING(roomID)
INNER JOIN Furniture USING(furnatureID)
```

This would give a row per furniture item.  You can squash it down in some SQL dialects with a `GROUP_CONCAT()`

```
SELECT r.*, GROUP_CONCAT(f.type) FROM Room AS r
LEFT JOIN RoomHasFurnature USING(roomID)
INNER JOIN Furniture AS f USING(furnatureID)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should ad a relational table named eg: room_forniture  for join the each room the the  various forniture

```
Room Table
roomID: 5
size: 15
wallColor: Blue


Room_forniture Table 
rooID: 5
fornitureID = 2

Room_forniture Table 
rooID: 5
fornitureID = 4

Room_forniture Table 
rooID: 5
fornitureID = 5


Furniture Table
furnitureID 2
type: table
color: wood

Furniture Table
furnitureID 4
type: closet
color: wood
 ......
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for many-to-many data model. You will need another table that will keep the relationship between room and furniture. Also look for normalization-denormalization.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)